# NASM/Yasm drops CALL after comment ending with backslash

Tags: assembly, nasm, yasm, intel-syntax

I am currently trying to built my own boot loader and noticed something peculiar.

When below code is assembled with NASM or Yasm without the marked NOP command the following CALL is missing from the binary. With the NOP included the CALL is correctly assembled but the op code 0x90 (NOP) is not present in the binary (later is understandable due to the nature of NOP).

```
to_hex_ascii:
        add al, '0'
        cmp al, 0x3a
        jl .end
;           add al, 0x07
            add al, 0x27
    .end:
        ret

print_word_hex:
        push bp
        mov bp, sp

        mov dx, [bp + 4]
        push dx
        mov al, dh
        push ax             ;\
        nop                 ; | <- NOP in question
        call print_lsb_hex  ; print_lsb_hex(ax);
        add sp, 2           ;/
        pop dx
        jmp print_lsb_hex.continue
print_lsb_hex:
        push bp
        mov bp, sp

        mov dl, [bp + 4]
    .continue:
        mov ah, 0x0e
        ; 0xf0
        mov al, dl
        and al, 0xf0
        shr al, 4
        call to_hex_ascii
        int 0x10  ; BIOS print call
        ; 0x0f
        mov al, dl
        and al, 0x0f
        call to_hex_ascii
        int 0x10  ; BIOS print call

        pop bp
        ret
```

Comment: The backslash character, '\', as the last thing on a line, is Nasm's "line continuation character". By putting it in a comment, the comment is continued to the next line - commenting out the `nop` or `call`. (it is not the nature of `nop` to just disappear like that!). Lose it, or put something after it.

Comment: Yes, so when you remove the `nop` line it is the `call` which becomes commented out.

Comment: Also; complying with C calling conventions (and passing parameters on the stack instead of in registers and diddling with "stack frame pointer") is the sign of an assembly language programmer that will never be able to fit everything they need into a "< 512 bytes" boot loader.. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The backslash character, '\', as the last thing on a line, is Nasm's "line continuation character". By putting it in a comment, the comment is continued to the next line - commenting out the nop or call. (it is not the nature of nop to just disappear like that!). Lose it, or put something after it.

–  Frank Kotler

---

From the NASM manual, [3.1 Layout of a NASM Source Line](https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html):

> NASM uses backslash (`\`) as the line continuation character; **if a line ends with backslash, the next line is considered to be a part of the backslash-ended line.**